# How to properly test for an empty string in c

Tags: c, string, parsing, null

I didn't see any answers in C for this so I am hoping i could get the down and dirty explanation from the C community. I have a char *ptr that I am testing that it is NOT an empty string or NULL but my if statement fails even though I can see that the value is in fact an empty string.

Screenshot:

[image]

The Code:

```
char **strsplit(char *str, const char delims[], size_t *len) {
    char *save, *tok;              /* holds str_tok val btwn calls */
    char **result = '\0';    /* set result to NULL */
    char *tmp = strdup(str); /* leaves original str intact */
    size_t delims_size = strlen(delims);
    size_t count = 0;        /* number of main strings */
    size_t sub_count = 0;    /* number of substrings */
    int i = 0;

    /* get number of delims in str */
    while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, delims)) != NULL) {
        tmp += delims_size;
        count++;
    } count++; /* add one for trailing token */
    tmp = strdup(str);

    save = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str));
    result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);

    if (result && save) {
        while ((tok = strstr(tmp, delims)) != NULL) {
            strncpy(save, tmp, (tok - tmp));
            save[(tok - tmp)] = '\0';
            printf("Token extracted: <<%s>>\n", save);
            result[i++] = strdup(save);
            tok += delims_size;
            tmp = tok;
        } /* grab trailing token */
        if (tmp != NULL && tmp[0] != "") {
            result[i++] = strdup(tmp);
            printf("Token extracted: <<%s>>\n", tmp);
        } /* set last ptr to NULL */
        result[i] = '\0';
        *len = count; /* pass num toks */
    }
    else { /* set len to 0 on error */
        *len = 0;
    }
    if (save) free(save);
    return result;
}
```

Implementation:

```
printf("processing client request\n");
size_t *num_tokens = malloc(sizeof(size_t));           /* num of tokens */
size_t *num_sub_tokens = malloc(sizeof(size_t));       /* num of tokens */
char **tokens = strsplit(req, "\r\n", num_tokens);     /* parse it */
```

I am trying to get the empty line in after the HTTP headers but when client does a GET request the body is "" and its not getting caught by my if statement. The same function using a POST reauest with data in the body produces output like this:

(This is my stdout)

```
Token extracted: <<POST /index.html HTTP/1.0>>
Token extracted: <<Host: 0.0.0.0>>
Token extracted: <<Content-Length: 1053>>
Token extracted: <<>>
Token extracted: <<"hello world">>
```

The GET request should not have the extra trailing token here:

(GET request stdout)

```
processing client request
Token extracted: <<GET index.html HTTP/1.0>>
Token extracted: <<Host: 0.0.0.0>>
Token extracted: <<>>
Token extracted: <<>>
```

This causes issues when parsing, although I may be able to come up with a witty solution like checking until first null on a GET request then replacing next token with the query string or NULL if not present. What is everyones take on this??

EDIT: added the full function and the implementation calls to make it more clear

Comment: Your question is not clear. your output not matching with your code.

Comment: Try tp make a MCVE,  combine the trouble code part with some fixed input buffer instead of the web stuff

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: Well, you can't test with `tmp[0] != ""`. If `tmp` is an array of `char`s, then `tmp[0]` is a `char`, and you want to test for `tmp[0] != '\0'`.

Comment: `if (tmp && strlen(tmp)) { printf("string is not empty"); }`

Comment: @DavidBowling I went through a few other trials after seeing your post and this was the one I was looking for : tmp[0] != '\0'   THANKS!  Now just have to figure out how to parse this query string :)

Comment: @Brandon your answer works flawlessly as well thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon an David mentioned comparing the first element of the string to NULL or testing the length to ensure the string contains more than 0 chars worked flawlessly! Code they posted is reiterated for convenience below:

Compare first elem to null:

```
if (tmp[0] != '\0') { printf("string is not empty"); }
```

Check length of string:

```
if (tmp && strlen(tmp)) { printf("string is not empty"); }
```